# How to display the input box in select2?

Tags: javascript, typescript, asp.net-core, jquery-select2

I am working in asp.net core. And I am using typescript. I am using select2 option.

HTML:-

```
<select multiple id="e1" class="js-example-basic-multiple js-states form-control">
<option value="AL">Alabama</option>
<option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
<option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
<option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
<option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

Script:-

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
     $(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2();
     });
  </script>
```

style:-

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

script:-

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

This is my code. I get output like this.

[image]

The input box is not appear. I want like this:

[image]

When I click in the box, the popup should appear like below:

[image]

How can I achieve it?

I write a html and script code in partial view. And I add a css and js file in layout html file.

Comment: Can anyone suggest what mistake I done?

Answer (score 0):

Try below example. the code in the question don't have closing **< script >** tag.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <head>
          <meta charset = "UTF-8">
          <meta http-equiv = "X-UA-Compatible" content = "IE = edge,chrome = 1">
          <title>Hello World using select2.js</title>
          <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>  

       </head>

       <body>
         <select multiple id="e1" class="js-example-basic-multiple js-states form-control">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
    <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
    <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>
       </body>
       <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
         $(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2();
         });
         </script>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine here,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <select multiple id="e1" class="js-example-basic-multiple js-states form-control">
            <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
            <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
            <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
            <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
            <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        </select>
 </body>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2();
    });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I write a html code and script  in partial view... And css and js file are added in layout html file.